# Raspberry Pi NetBeans running jar with sudo

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, raspberry-pi, sudo

I am trying to use Pi4J and when I attempt to run my program NetBeans says

> WiringPiSetup: Must Be root:did you forget sudo?

Is there a way to fix this? I'm new to NetBeans and Raspberry Pi and I want to compile and run everything on the Raspberry Pi itself.

Comment: [I think you have to run NetBeans as root.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/529582/how-to-run-netbeans-8-0-as-root)

Answer (score 1):

go to "Java platform manager" 
Under "platform properties"-"Exec Prefix" enter sudo

Good luck